# What is this spoon-like kitchen utensil with a rubbery head and wooden handle called?

Tags: equipment

What is this utensil or kitchen tool called that has a rubber-like head and a wooden handle? 
What is it used for?

[image: rubber head tool]

Comment: If you ever need reminding of what it's called:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XbCWmY0eqY

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is usually called a rubber spatula, even though they're rarely made of rubber. The ones I find most useful are made of silicone, and are heatproof. [This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H0OP4A) by OXO is one of my favorite gadgets.

They're for stirring and for clean scraping bowls and jars and such. The heatproof ones are great for use with non-stick cookware while sauteing.

Comment: I have that OXO one, but I much prefer the all silicone coated steel core ones like this: http://www.amazon.com/Silicone-Spatula-Set-Compliant-Resistant/dp/B00HDABAQS.  The joint between the silicone head and plastic handle can get funky on the OXO one.

Comment: @Tremmors Is the head of the OXO one not detachable for cleaning? I have a couple of very cheap silicone spatulas and every now and again, I just pull the heads off and clean them. (I agree that the ones you link that avoid that completely would be a definite improvement.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby The head does come off for cleaning, but I never feel like I can really get in there to clean the cavity properly.

Comment: @Tremmors Yeah, those look pretty cool, but you'll only get mine from my cold dessicated hands! (I love that gadget) Since it goes easily in the dishwasher, crannies don't bother me.

Answer (score 4):

Although I grew up calling them a 'rubber spatula' (and most of 'em are silicone these days), I've also heard them referred to as a 'rubber scaper'.

There are also 'bowl scapers' which are effectively a larger head of a rubber scraper; there's no handle, which gives you better leverage for really scaping sticky things out of a large bowl.

Comment: Yep, and the wooden handle in the OP would not be *charming*.

Comment: @Jolenealaska : in many cases, I prefer wooden handles; I've snapped way too many plastic handled spatulas when trying to scrape something particularly sticky.